# How to configure active directory activation from powershell/commandline?

Tags: windows-server-2016, activation, kms

Although it's a simple matter to configure Active Directory activation on Windows Server 2016 once the VA role is installed using the GUI, I need a way to configure this from the command line or preferably from powershell, however, I can't seem to find any powershell modules for this role.

Has anyone done this before?

PS. I am not looking to set up a KMS host using `slmgr.vbs`. I need to install a KMS key for active directory activation as you can do in the Volume Activation Tools GUI.

Comment: slmgr.vbs is also used to manage MAK activation (at least on previous version, not sure on 2016)

Comment: @JFL I know, thanks, I'm not looking to do MAK activation, I'm looking to install a KMS key for active directory activation, not set up a KMS host. I'll clarify the question.

Comment: if using a volume licensing media for installation, it should be configured for this out of the box. Isn't it the case?

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found out how you can do it, still using slmgr.vbs:

```
slmgr.vbs /ad-activation-online <kms key>
```